# Nuget package containging different dll versions in ref / lib folders

Tags: .net, dll, nuget, .net-standard

I have an issue with System.ComponentModel.Annotations v4.5.0.

After I updated to this version, my app crashes due to a `FileLoadException (Could not load file or assembly 'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)`.

This package is used in a library project targeting `netstandard2.0`, which is then used by a Webapi project targeting `net461`.

Upon inspection, it turned out that this nuget package contains mismatching versions in the `ref` and `lib` folders for `netstandard2.0` target (for `net461` target the versions match).

The version in `ref/netstandard2.0` which is used for compilation is `4.2.0.0` but the one in `lib/netstandard2.0` that's used in runtime is `4.2.1.0`, hence the error I have. You can download the package from NuGet Gallery and notice the mismatch by inspecting its contents.

Is this version msimatch in the same nuget package something to be expected in which case I'll use a binding redirect or is this a problem with the package itself ?

Comment: Hmm, I do get 4.2.1.0 as the reference assembly when I use that Nuget package.  But am probably not using the same project type, it  supports a lot of them, you need to document that.

Comment: Thanks. I documented project types as requested.

Comment: Yup, they fumbled that.  DLL Hell is a rampant problem lately, .netstandard caused a lot of mayhem.  You could consider to use version 4.4.1 of the package, it doesn't have the same bug and uses v4.2.0.0 for both the reference and the runtime assembly.  Odd regression btw.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [binding redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) in your app.config to resolve version,

here an exemple:

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.0.0" newVersion="4.5.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I did to solve the problem but my question was about wether having the same nuget package containing different version is something to be expected and handled by a binding redirect or is it a problem with the package.